# How to write a TUI in RHEL/CentOS

Tags: centos, rhel, tui

Does anybody know if the `system-config-..-tui` commands use a shared library for building their TUIs? Is it possible to write a Bash Script with the same TUI interface (no GTK/GNOME/KDE - pure Text)?

Comment: This question belongs on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Have you even tried looking at them? A quick check of their source (if python) or linked libraries (if binaries) should tell you easily enough. If you don't want to go find development docs about them or look at their sources directly.